# Laravel - check if entry with a certain string already exists in database

Tags: php, laravel, api, rest

I have something like a form, and I want to prevent people from submitting the form or better to say, the Laravel API from saving the data into the database. People have to link their social media to this form, and it is stored as json `{"id":"b3931aba-a58e-4f0f-a4fa-4afda75035cd","value":"testusername"}`. And if somebody already submitted the form with a certain social media name, I want my api to check if there is an entry that contains an entry with the value testusername, and if so, then throw an error that the person already submitted them form, but my code does not work - it responds Couldn't connect to server (though when I remove the check in the controller it works fine).

That is the code in my Controller

```
$requestPerson = $request->all();

if(Person::alreadySubmit($request->id, $requestPerson['personInteraction']['socialMedia'])) {
    return $this->badRequestResponder->validationError(['message' => 'Person has already submitted for the given username!']);
}
```

and then I have my Person models file with the method

```
 public static function alreadySubmit($formId, $socialMedia)
    {
        return self::where([['form_id', '=', $formId], ['socialMedia', 'like', $socialMedia]])->exists();
    }
```

Comment: I think you can do something like create a validator and check for uniqueness, like described here: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-unique

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend using a `like` in the where statement. This might gather multiple records from the database that are not equal to the provided input.

I would recommend to use the following code in the model:

```
return self::where('socialMedia', '=', $socialMedia )
    ->where('form_id', '=', $formId)
    ->exists();
```

Another good practice is to add an unique constraint in MySQL with an unique index on the columns `socialMedia` & `formId`.

You can create a laravel Migration with the statement:
`php artisan make:migration alterTablePersonAddUniqueIndexOnSocialMedia`

Then add the following code in the migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('persons', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unique(['socialMedia', 'formId']);
    });
}
```

Then run it by: `php artisan migrate`

> Couldn't connect to server (though when I remove the check in the
> controller it works fine).

Check your connection setting from your database in the .ENV file. Make sure everything is setup correctly.

Comment: Yeah but the thing is that there are multiple forms (they can be created), and only for the created form with the created form_id a person should be able to only submit once with their social media handle

Comment: Also, the id in the json file can be different, and if a person submits with one social media the json would be only the same if the person submits the form identically again, but a person can provide multiple social media handles, which makes it impossible to make the json unique, because there will be a lot of possible variations, the only way would be to store the handles without json, but I don't want to rewrite the existing logic